# Creating a simplified page for web scrapers

Tags: php, web-scraping

A client of mine has a very stylized web page with vacancies, this includes things like tables, graphs, and forms. This looks great when someone visits their website but a lot of other sites scrape the web page and show the vacancy on their site.

Previously their site was a simple page with some basic markup such as headers, paragraphs, and bold texts. The other websites picked this up just fine but with the more advanced markup, they're falling behind.

How could I make a special page for the web scrapers? To be more specific: **how could I detect in PHP that a web scraper is looking at the page?** From there on I could figure out how to make a custom CMS page for the client so they can use it to fill in the simple markup theirself.

Comment: It really depends on what the web scrappers are looking for. Some will use html 5 markup and look for article and H1 tags for example. Others can use microdata. Others will be set to look for specific keywords or html tags. But user agent might be something you can use to detect a web scrapping bot, provided they are providing it and not just a browser user agent.

Comment: Web scraping is a clutch. Investigate if there's a common API or JSON/XML format, and implement that instead.

Comment: From my understanding: You want the scrapers to get the data on the page, to make things easier on both sides, why don't you look into making an API for them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, headers, paragraph, etc. are good markup. If the "advanced markup" doesn't have these, then it's not "advanced markup" at all, but **bad** markup. So irregardless if your pages are being scraped you should be using [semantic markup](https://www.google.com/search?q=semantic%20markup) anyway. Additionally there are more ways to give the HTML meaning such as [microdata](https://www.google.com/search?q=html%20microdata).

But since you seem know the web scrapers (or at least know about them) and have given them permission (implicitly or explicitly) to crawl the site, then their operators should provide documentation, that tells you what exactly what they are looking for.

Preferably these operators shouldn't be using webscapers at all, but they should recieve the information they are looking for from you in a structured way, such as JSON or XML which you generate additionally to the regular HTML pages.